# Find all method name in one flow of code

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I just want to know if there is any API or any thing which tells me all the method name which have been executed during one execution of application.

For ex. Lets say I have application with 10000 methods and based on some condition different methods get executed. So during one execution lets say if 100 method getting executed then I would like to know name of all these 100 methods in order of their execution.

is it possible?

Comment: I don't know...logging and testing (code coverage), maybe?

Comment: A code profiler may be able to help you get a list of methods. You could also use AspectJ or another framework to introspect and log every method call in your application (or in someone else's application)!

Comment: I don't think java maintains any kind of record for the executed methods ..i doubt if any other language too.. but i am not quite sure.

Comment: You can use aspects to fire actions when some methods are executed.

Comment: @Luiggi in that I need to know all the method name that is to be executed.or need to remember the action to be fired on each method call.

Comment: No, you can use a pattern to define the methods that will fall in the aspect. At least review the technology first...

Answer (score 3):

There are few options you can use to track your method calls. 

**1.** JProfiler http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html 

**2.** Your kit. http://www.yourkit.com/ 

**3.** In addition you can write an application that logs to file when enters to methods and exit using Aspects with Log4j or SL4j